# Computing the Chern-Simons invariant of $SO(3)$

Tags: differential-geometry

I am an undergraduate learning about gauge theory and I have been tasked with working through the two examples given on pages 65 and 66 of "[Characteristic forms and geometric invariants](http://www.jstor.org/pss/1971013)" by Chern and Simon. I will recount the examples and my progress at a solution. For ease here is the relevant text:

> *Example 1.* Let $M = \mathbb{R}P^3 = SO(3)$ together with the standard metric of constant curvature 1. Let $E_1, E_2, E_3$ be an orthonormal basis of left invariant fields on $M$, oriented positively. Then it is easily seen that $\nabla_{E_1}E_2 = E_3, \nabla_{E_1}E_3 = - E_2, \text{ and } \nabla_{E_2}E_3 = E_1$. Let $\chi : M \rightarrow F(M)$ be the cross-section determined by this frame.
>   $$\Phi(SO(3)) = \frac{1}{2}.$$
>
> *Example 2.* Again let $M = SO(3)$, but this time with left invariant metric $g_{\lambda}$, with respect to which $\lambda E_1, E_2, E_3$ is an orthonormal frame. Direct calculation shows
>   $$\Phi(SO(3),g_{\lambda}) = \frac{2\lambda^2 - 1}{2\lambda^4}.$$

For each of these examples I am expected to calculate
$$\Phi(M) = \int_{\chi(M)} \frac{1}{2} TP_1(\theta)$$
which lies in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$. Previously in the paper they give an explicit formulation of $TP_1(\theta)$ in terms of the "component" forms of the connection $\theta$ and its curvature $\Omega$,
$$TP_1(\theta) = \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\left( \theta_{12}\wedge\theta_{13}\wedge\theta_{23} + \theta_{12}\wedge\Omega_{12} + \theta_{13}\wedge\Omega_{13} + \theta_{23}\wedge\Omega_{23}\right).$$

I have verified this formula for myself given the information in the paper. Using the structural equation $\Omega = d\theta + \theta\wedge\theta$ I am able to reduce the expression for $TP_1(\theta)$ to
$$TP_1(\theta) = \frac{-1}{2\pi^2}\left( \theta_{12}\wedge\theta_{13}\wedge\theta_{23} \right).$$

I don't believe I have assumed anything about the structure of $M$ during that reduction so I believe it should hold for both examples. I continue by claiming that since $E_1, E_2, E_3 \in so(3)$, the Lie algebra of $SO(3)$ I should be able to compute $\theta$ by considering
$$\nabla_{E_i}E_j := (\nabla E_j)(E_i) = \sum_k E_k \otimes \theta^{k}{}_{ij}(E_i)$$
and comparing it with the given derivatives.

For example one this yielded for me $\theta_{12} = E^3, \theta_{13} = -E^2, \theta_{23} = E^1$ where $E^i$ are the 1-forms dual to the basis $E_i$. Then I think that $\chi^*$ should act trivially on $TP_1(\theta)$ as it is a horizontal form in $\Lambda^*(T^*F(M))$. Therefore I find that $\chi^*(TP_1(\theta)) = \frac{1}{2\pi^2}\omega$, where $\omega$ is the volume form of $M$, and when integrated this yields the correct answer of $\frac{1}{2}$ for the first example.

However, my approach fails completely for the second example. I assume that the set $\lambda E_1, E_2, E_3$ obeys the same derivate relationships as given in the first example, but this does not seem to give me enough factors of $\lambda$. I suspect that I am not handling the computation of the $\theta_{ij}$ forms or the application of $\chi^*$ correctly, however I am uncertain what my exact issue is. Is there a fundamental flaw in my understanding? I am hoping someone with more experience can point me in the right direction.

Comment: In simplifying the expression for $T_1(\theta)$ using the structure equation, what happens to the terms that are like $\theta_{12} \wedge d\theta_{12}$?

Comment: This has also been asked on [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/q/47560/21564) where it has received a partial answer.

Comment: The problem lies in the deformation you have applied to the sphere, which messes up the covariant derivative and the volume form. If everything is calculated with this in mind, you get the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

I will use co-frames. If $\bar{\theta}_1$, $\bar{\theta}_2$ and $\bar{\theta}_3$ is the co-frame dual to $E_1$, $E_2$ and $E_3$, then the co-frame dual to $\lambda E_1$, $E_2$ and $E_3$ is:

$\theta_1 = \lambda^{-1} \bar{\theta}_1$, $\theta_2 = \bar{\theta}_2$ and $\theta_3 = \bar{\theta}_3$.

We then have:
$d \theta_1 + 2\lambda^{-1} \theta_2 \wedge \theta_3 = 0$,
$d \theta_2 +2 \lambda \theta_3 \wedge \theta_1 = 0$ and 
$d \theta_3 + 2 \lambda \theta_1 \wedge \theta_2 = 0$.

From Cartan's first structure equation $d \theta_i + \sum_j \theta_{ij} \wedge \theta_j = 0$, we then deduce that
$\theta_{12} = -\lambda^{-1} \theta_3$, $\theta_{13} = \lambda^{-1} \theta_2$ and $\theta_{23} = (\lambda^{-1}-2\lambda) \theta_1$.

We then compute the curvature $2$-forms $\Omega_{ij} = d\theta_{ij} + \sum_k \theta_{ik} \wedge \theta_{kj}$. We obtain

$\Omega_{12} = \lambda^{-2} \theta_1 \wedge \theta_2$, $\Omega_{13} = \lambda^{-2} \theta_1 \wedge \theta_3$ and $\Omega_{23} = (4-3\lambda^{-2}) \theta_2 \wedge \theta_3$.

We then get that
$\frac{1}{2} TP_1(\theta) = \frac{1}{2\pi^2}(-\lambda^{-4}+2\lambda^{-2}-2)Vol_{SO(3)}$, where $Vol_{SO(3)}$ denotes the volume form of the round $SO(3)$ (i.e. corresponding to $\lambda = 1$).

Since the volume of the round $SO(3)$ is $\pi^2$, the formula for the Chern-Simons invariant of $g_\lambda$ now follows.

Edit 1: I will provide more details. Using the formula (I think $6.1$ in that Chern-Simons paper):

$$TP_1(\theta) = \frac{1}{4\pi^2}\left( \theta_{12}\wedge\theta_{13}\wedge\theta_{23} + \theta_{12}\wedge\Omega_{12} + \theta_{13}\wedge\Omega_{13} + \theta_{23}\wedge\Omega_{23}\right),$$

we get that

\begin{align*} \frac{1}{2} TP_1(\theta) = &\frac{1}{8 \pi^2} \left(-\lambda^{-1}\lambda^{-1}(\lambda^{-1}-2\lambda) \, \theta_3 \wedge \theta_2 \wedge \theta_1 \right. \\
&-\lambda^{-1} \lambda^{-2} \, \theta_3 \theta_1 \theta_2 + \lambda^{-1} \lambda^{-2} \, \theta_2 \wedge \theta_1 \wedge \theta_3 \\
&\left.\,+(\lambda^{-1} - 2\lambda)(4 - 3\lambda^{-2}) \, \theta_1 \wedge \theta_2 \wedge \theta_3\right) \\
& = \frac{1}{2 \pi^2}(-\lambda^{-3} + 2\lambda^{-1} - 2\lambda) \, \theta_1 \wedge \theta_2 \wedge \theta_3
\end{align*}
But remember the formulas
$\theta_1 = \lambda^{-1} \bar{\theta}_1$, $\theta_2 = \bar{\theta}_2$ and $\theta_3 = \bar{\theta}_3$.
We thus pick up an extra factor of $\lambda^{-1}$ when written in terms of the standard volume form on $SO(3)$. This is how I obtained:

$$\frac{1}{2} TP_1(\theta) = \frac{1}{2\pi^2}(-\lambda^{-4}+2\lambda^{-2}-2)\,Vol_{SO(3)}.$$

Finally, since the volume of $SO(3)$ is $\pi^2$, we get that

$$\Phi(g_{\lambda}) \equiv \frac{1}{2}(-\lambda^{-4} + 2 \lambda^{-2} -2) \equiv -\frac{1}{2} \lambda^{-4} + \lambda^{-2} \quad \text{(mod $\mathbb{Z}$)},$$

which is what Chern and Simons wrote, up to a minor algebraic manipulation. Yes, it is a tricky calculation!

Edit 2: I will explain how to obtain the connection $1$-forms $\theta_{ij}$. We should have

$$d\theta_1 + \theta_{12} \wedge \theta_2 + \theta_{13} \wedge \theta_3 = 0.$$

We have that $d\theta_1 + 2 \lambda^{-1} \theta_2 \wedge \theta_3 = 0$.

It can be shown that $\theta_{12} = h \theta_3$. Basically, if $\theta_{12}$ has a non-zero $\theta_1$ component, then this would lead to a non-zero $\theta_1 \wedge \theta_2$ component of $d\theta_1$, which is a contradiction. It can similarly be shown that $\theta_{12}$ has no $\theta_2$ component either.

A similar reasoning gives that:
$$\theta_{12} = h\, \theta_3 \text{ , } \theta_{31} = g \,\theta_2 \text{ and } \theta_{23} = f \,\theta_1.$$

We therefore have, using the first two equations in edit 2, that:

$$ -g - h = 2 \lambda^{-1} .$$

Using similar equations for $d\theta_2$ and $d\theta_3$, we get that:

$$ -f - h = 2 \lambda, $$
$$ -f - g = 2 \lambda. $$

Solving these $3$ linear equations in $f, g$ and $h$ yields

$$f = \lambda^{-1} - 2\lambda \text{ , } g = -\lambda^{-1} \text{ , } h = -\lambda^{-1}.$$

Therefore, we have that

$\theta_{12} = -\lambda^{-1} \theta_3$, $\theta_{13} = \lambda^{-1} \theta_2$ and $\theta_{23} = (\lambda^{-1}-2\lambda) \theta_1.$

Comment: How do you go from the expression involving $-\lambda^{-4} + 2\lambda^{-2} -2$ to the one in the original paper? You integrate the volume, but why is the final answer the addition of two instead of three terms?

Comment: @AlonsoPerezLona, it has been a while, I have to redo the calculation to remember. One moment.

Comment: thank you very much. I would appreciate any other details on the calculation that you have. For instance, exactly how you computed $TP(\theta)$ from $\Omega_{ij}$ and $\theta_{ij}$. I am trying to do the calculation with a code I came up with, but I get different results.

Comment: @AlonsoPerezLona, My calculation is a little long. I reproduced it. The answer to your question is because the Chern-Simons invariant lives in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$, so it is defined modulo the integers. This is how you get from $3$ terms to $2$ terms, as in the Chern-Simons paper. Also, at the end, you pick up an extra factor of $\lambda^{-1}$ when you go from the "Berger" frame to the round/standard frame on $SO(3)$. In case you want more details on a specific part of the calculation, let me know please, and I will explain. It would take me a long time to write down all the details though.

Comment: @AlonsoPerezLona, to calculate $TP(\theta)$, I just used formula $6.1$ (I think) in the paper, which the OP reproduced in the post. Which computer language are you using by the way?

Comment: I am using Mathematica. I got an answer of $\frac{(1-4 \lambda^2 + 2\lambda^4)}{\lambda^3 \pi^2} Vol_{SO(3)}$. Taking into account the extra $\lambda^-1$ factor that you mention, my answer kind of looks like yours, but not exactly. I know that my $\theta_{ij}$ and $\Omega_{ij}$ are the same as yours, so I am not exactly sure why my computations don't agree with yours (and for that matter with the paper).

Comment: Could you provide more details on adding that extra $\lambda^{-1}$ factor?

Comment: @AlonsoPerezLona, I edited my answer and provided more details.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on how you got the structure constants $\lambda^{-1}$ and $(\lambda^{-1} - 2\lambda)$?

Comment: That'd be very helpful

Comment: @AlonsoPerezLona. I edited again. Now my answer is more or less complete! I hope this helps.

Comment: The first equation in Edit 2 is one of Cartan's structure equations. Where did the second one, the one with the $2\lambda^{-1}$ factores come from?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98489/discussion-between-malkoun-and-alonso-perez-lona).

Comment: is it possible to calculate the Chern-Simons invariant without using a metric? Or in what sense is this invariant metric-independent?

Comment: Thm. 6.3 in the paper by Chern and Simons says that the Chern-Simons invariant is a conformal invariant. So a compact oriented $3$-manifold $M$ with two conformally related metrics $g$ and $g' = fg$, where $f$ is a smooth positive function on $M$, have the same CS invariants.The two examples that the OP asked about show that it is *not* a topological invariant.

Comment: So why is it that many people call the CS form a topological invariant?

Comment: I am talking about the Chern-Simons invariant associated to $(M,g)$ where $M$ is a compact oriented $3$-manifold $M$ and $g$ is a metric. You are talking about the topological quantum field theory based on the Chern-Simons form, known as Chern-Simons theory. I don't know much about it, but I can tell you that it is a gauge theoretic version of the Chern-Simons invariant associated to a metric. It is related to connections on a principal $G$-bundle on a compact oriented $3$-manifold $M$. Perhaps ask on the Physics SE, but expect a physicist's answer.

Comment: And so it does not make sense to computer this CS invariant for non-compact manifolds, right?

Comment: Well, you want to make sure that the integral converges. If you don't have compactness, you probably need to impose some decay conditions to make sure that the integral converges.